# Create Subsite using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using below script to create a sub site using custom site template:-

```
function CreateWebsite()
{    

    var title = "test";
    var description = "test site";
    var webUrl= "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite/";
    var templateTitle = "testTemplate";


    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    var webTemplates = web.getAvailableWebTemplates(1033,false);
    context.load(webTemplates);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            var enumerator = webTemplates.getEnumerator();
            var customTemplate;
            while(enumerator.moveNext())
            {
                var webTemplate = enumerator.get_current();
                var webTitle = webTemplate.get_title();
                if(webTitle == templateTitle) // templateTitle = Custom Tempalte Title
                {
                    customTemplate = webTemplate.get_name();
                    break;
                }
            }                
            var webCreationInformation = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
            webCreationInformation.set_title(title);
            webCreationInformation.set_description(description);
            webCreationInformation.set_language(1033);
            webCreationInformation.set_url(webUrl);
            webCreationInformation.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
            webCreationInformation.set_webTemplate(customTemplate);
            web.get_webs().add(webCreationInformation);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
                alert('Website created successfully.');
            }, 
            function(sender, args){ 
                alert(args.get_message());
                });
        }, 
        function(sender, args){ 
            alert(args.get_message())
        }
    );
}
```

I am getting error "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite/" contains invalid character ':'."

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to create a sub site, you no need to provide full web url.
Just provide a URL relative to the root website in the site collection.

For ex., 
If you want to create a subsite named "newsite" under "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite/". Assume Site Collection url is "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite"

Just give `webUrl = "newsite"`
The code will create newSite under the testSite.